# $.slideToggle() & $.hover() animation queue issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set up a pretty basic hover animation in jQuery. Mouse over a div and the major content is slid down, mouse up and it slides up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.listItem').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.errorData').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });</script>
```

This piece of code works fine, but the obvious problem is the animation queuing if you mouse in and out really quickly.

To alleviate this I have read that the `.stop(true)` function placed before the `.slideToggle()` stops the previous animation and clears the animation queue. So I tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.listItem').hover(function () {
            $(this).find('.errorData').stop(true).slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });</script>
```

My problem now is that this only seems to work on the first mousein and mouseout. After that the animations no longer trigger and nothing happens. This is Google Chrome DEV channel.

This seems to be exacerbated by how fast you move the mouse in and out.

I can't seem to work out what the issue is, this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNhky/) has a working (and breaking on my computer) example.

EDIT: I suspect this is a bug in jQuery 1.4.2 and have lodged a bug ticket: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6772

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
.stop(true,true)
```

---

or you can use this [**hoverIntent plugin**](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: this kinda works. It rectifies the issue of the animation no longer working, but it now jumps back and forth and flickers, instead of a smooth animation.

Comment: yes... really it will. it's because of the behavior of hover... well, you can try this plugin... I use it in times like this, http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: The plugin gave me pretty much the functionality I wanted. Amend your answer and i'll make it as such :)

Comment: well, I'm glad it did help you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.stop(true, true)
```

works like a champ:

```
  $('.subpage-block').hover(function(){

        $('.subpage-block-heading span', this).stop(true,true).fadeToggle('fast');

           $('.subpage-block-content', this).stop(true,true).slideToggle();

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

MayBe better?

```
$('.listitem').hover(function(){
  if (!$(this).find('.errorData').hasClass('down') &&
      !$(this).find('.errorData').hasClass('up')) {
    $(this).find('.errorData').addClass('down').slideDown('fast', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('down');
    });
  }
}, function() {
  if (!$(this).find('.errorData').hasClass('up')) {
    $(this).find('.errorData').addClass('up').slideUp('fast', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('up');
    });
  }
});
```

This way the queue is at most 2, one when is up and other when is down.
With the first condition we prevents to stay down.

Comment: How does this improve, correct, or change the accepted answer?