# jquery ul multi-lvl menu dont show

Tags: jquery, menu

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9m9k/) - I want normal, multi-level menu openable on hover (bbb items has sub menu). It works ok, but when you hover and 'de-hover' on some bbb item quickly few times and than try to open sub-menu and another sub-sub-menu it doesnt work ok.

When I remove `.stop()` it works ok, but I cant do this to make it look nice.

Comment: I don't see any issue in chrome. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177446/slidetoggle-hover-animation-queue-issue